# Placement of validation messages with images

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Here's my code:

```
rules: {
    firstname:"required",
    lastname:"required",
       },
messages: 
       {
        firstname:"<img src='icons/xmark.png' /> Enter your first name",
        lastname:"<img src='icons/xmark.png' />Enter your last name"
       }
```

and I am achieving this effect.

[image].

My question is, is there any other way using `jquery.validate()` to have the same effect but
the `<img src>` would be on another element or disappear from messages group? I already tried errorPlacement but I can't get it to work accordingly.

**NOTE: without grouping or using errorLabelContainer** ( because It messes the error messages when I'm grouping them).

Comment: You want the message in one place, the images somewhere else?

Comment: Yes. If possible, I will have 1 image src and append them to all the error messages for making my codes neat.

Comment: Maybe `errorLabelContainer` would be useful? Put the image in that element.

Comment: Already tried that but it messed up all the error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can develop a solution using the `wrapper` and `errorPlacement` settings as given below

```
$(function(){

  $('form').validate({
    rules: {
      name: {
        required: true
      },
      dob: {
        required: true
      },
      doj: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    wrapper:'span',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element){
      error.prepend('<img src="http://www.schneider-electric.com/download/resource/images/msg_error.gif" />')
      error.insertAfter(element);
    }
  })

});
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vAg4s9JO68WJe9thtEEl?p=preview)